# How to populate global namespace by import?

Tags: python, python-import

I have written a library that is roughly structured like this:

```py
# file library/module/core.py
class MyClass:
   backend = DesignatedBackend()

# file library/backends/backend_A.py
class DesignatedBackend:
    who = "I'm backend A"

# file library/backends/backend_B.py
class DesignatedBackend:
    who = "I'm backend B"
```

Then in IPython, or when running a script I would like to be able to write:

```py
>>> from library.module.core import MyClass
>>> import library.backends.backend_A # or something 

>>> print(MyClass().backend.who)
I'm backend A
```

i.e. I would like to set which classes are available in the global namespace of the library by issuing an appropriate import statement.

Comment: do you want to allow certain libraries to be available when accessing the codebase?

Comment: `library/module/core.py` doesn't import anything so it wont have any knowledge of what `DesignatedBackEnd` is meant to be.

Comment: I'm confused. `backend` is never assigned, only annotated, and `DesignatedBackend` is undefined in `library/module/core.py`. How are you expecting that to work? Also, in IPython, wouldn't you need to import the backend *before* `MyClass`?

Comment: Creates global mutable state / spooky action at a distance. Even though this is probably possible in Python, avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Because your core file doesn't import anything it can't resolve what `DesignatedBackEnd` is. Even if you could somehow inject the DesignatedBackEnd into the namespace of core it would be too late, as the core module can't exist until you import it, and that import will fail.

You could 'contrive' to have a factory method in core, so you import the core module, inject into the namespace and then dynamically create the appropriate class.

But the nicest way to do this is use composition :

```
# file library/module/core.py
class MyClass:
     def __init__(self, backend_type):
         self.backend = backend_type()

# file library/backends/backend_A.py
class DesignatedBackend:
    who = "I'm backend A"

# file library/backends/backend_B.py
class DesignatedBackend:
    who = "I'm backend B"
```

This way you can do :

```
>>> from library.module.core import MyClass
>>> from library.backends.backend_A import DesignatedBacEnd # or something 

>>> print(MyClass(DesignatedBackEnd).backend.who)
I'm backend A
```

Comment: Yes I know composition would be the best thing, but I cannot do this painlessly (the backend is used by objects that can be created at runtime and one would have to pass the appropriate backend each time, to each object)

Comment: @Ziofil sounds to me like your architecture is going to struggle then - the only other option is for core to have some fix-up and factory methods to inject the chosen backend into the core namespace and then a factory method to dynamically create the class - but that is horrible to be frank.

Comment: I think you meant `self.backend = backend()`, probably more clear if you name it `backend_type`, so `backend = backend_type()` Also, while this is composition, so what the OP's original approach, I think you meant dependency injection

Comment: I am not sure what I would characterise the OPs approach as - as he wrote it would never work.